# Android SDK source code for this API level cannot be found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got an error while debugging:

- The Android SDK of the device under debug has API level 30.
- Android SDK source code for this API level cannot be found.
  [image]

I have created a new Socket on the line:
socket = new Socket("ip", port);

I've checked Android SDK Platforms:
[image]

SDK Tools:
[image]

Android Studio version:
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Canary 11
Build #AI-233.14475.28.2331.11483111, built on February 22, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11446219 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows Server 2022 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true

Comment: The device you use doesn't matter for the source code. It is the targetSDK of the app that defines the Android framework that is used for compilation and thus for the source code.